# How to disable back button in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javasscript">
window.history.forward();
function noback()
{
window.history.forward();
}
</script>
</head>

    <body onload="noback();" onpageshow="if(event.persisted) ;" onunload="">
    <a href="a1.php">aa</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in HTML which forwards you to same page when you click back, but how to include this script in `PHP` code.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: @sunny he wants to block the back button of the browser. For whatever reason. Just another annoying JavaScript guy like those who try to prevent the download of their images with JS ...

Answer (score 0):

You can for example do something like that:

```
<?php
Your PHP Code
?>
Your Html code
<?php
Your PHP Code
?>
Your Html code
<?php
Your PHP Code
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
Your PHP Code
...
echo "Your HTML code";
...
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, better mess up PHP and HTML ... i dont think there are things like template engines ...

Comment: @YUNOWORK : It all depends on what is wanted ... I only gave two examples, but of course there are others. :)

Answer (score 0):

just change the extension of your file

> .html/.htm

to

> .php
>   And put your php code in this .php file in head section